# Httpost method on ActionResult is not working to store data

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have `ActionResult` method that uses `Httpost`, but when I debug it does not get in the method, only ends in ActionResult for using `HttpGet`. What could be the main reason for this? I want to store value back to the database column, at this point it does non of that and have debug as well inspect nothing on the browser.

```
//GET/Courses-List
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CoursesRegistration()
{
    eNtsaCourses courses = new eNtsaCourses();
    //courses.Course = Course;
    return View();
}


[Route("Home/CoursesRegistration")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CoursesRegistration([Bind(Include = "Id,Course,Nickname,Term, EnrolledAs, Published")] eNtsaCourses courses)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            cb.eNtsaCourse.Add(courses);
            cb.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }
        
    return PartialView("CoursesRegistration", courses);
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("CoursesRegistration", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="testForm", @class="form-horizontal"})) { 
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Start New Course</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="CourseName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">CourseName</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "CourseName" } })

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="Content-Licence" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Content Licence</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                            
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                       
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("CoursesRegistration", "Home")" class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="$('#exampleModal').modal('show');">Create Courses</a>
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                $("#exampleModal.btn-success").click(function () {
                                                    saveData();
                                                });

                                                function saveData() {
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: "/Home/CoursesRegistration",
                                                        data: $('#testForm').serialize(),
                                                        type: 'post',
                                                        success: function (data) {
                                                            if (data.Success) {
                                                                $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
                                                            } else {

                                                            }

                                                        },
                                                        error: function (xhr, status) {

                                                        }
                                                       
                                                    });
                                                    return false;
                                                }


                                            </script>

                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
}
```

Comment: Hi T2020, did you get any JS errors? I notice you are overriding the form submit with an ajax call and js.

You could just use a razor object for all your form variables and use that on your viewmodel. then any submit button should post it to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

ok a couple of things, why in razor are you using a `Html.BeginForm` and then overriding that with ajax/js?

Best bet here would be choose one method and use that, my preference would be sticking the whole modal into a partial and using a C# object as the model for that partial, then you can use your beginform without having to mess around with ajax/js and serialisation.

Then you can have a single input of the model in your controller POST function.

Have you checked to see if the button is actually firing the js? I noticed you wired it up to

```
$("#exampleModal.btn-success").click(function () {
    saveData();
});
```

when it should be

```
$("#exampleModal .btn-success").click(function () {
    saveData();
});
```

maybe stick some console logs in to check and see if it fires and what the data is prior to sending.

Also change the controller function to a httpget to see if it is finding the route ok, then change back to post and you should know then if it is the controller, the route, or the frontend code. I suspect the frontend code.

Comment: @Spliposh i had a work around, the issue is on Httpost method its not getting in.

Comment: So the jqeury is firing but the controller is not being hit? Does it get hit if the http is changed to GET in the controller?

Comment: Yes jquery does fires, the issue is on httpost, httpget does not get any responce back with data being saved.

Comment: I'm unsure about your second statement, using breakpoints does it enter the function at all if it is changed to HttpGet?

Comment: It does only to HttpGet not HttPost

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).click(function);
```

If you are using multiple selector in jquery then take a space between two selector.
You need to use as below

```
$("#exampleModal .btn-success").click(function () {
saveData();
});
```

Comment: @Gajjar please clear me this for me, the selector attribute should be placed before the function call. eg. $(selector).click(function); then $("#exampleModal .btn-success).click(function () {...}?

Comment: Hello @T2020Jackson "$(selector).click(function);" is the syntax. you can check below link for use of multiple selector syntax, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_sel.asp . Change you cade as below '$("#exampleModal .btn-success").click(function () {saveData();});' or as comment.